# Why can't Node see an element in an array when it is chosen by variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, timeout

In a script I am writing, I am iterating over some messages in a mailbox and attempting to delete ones that have been read. The issue I have been getting though, is that as i iterate over the array, Node says that it cannot find the property id at the given element(which is necessary to delete or view anything). This would be fine if that property didn't exist, but when using util.inspect and specifying 1 instead of the iterator variable, it can find and print that field. The code as it exists is shown below:

```
             for(var b = 1; b < length; b++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                  console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
                  console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1], false, null));
                  console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1].id, false, null));
                  console.log(util.inspect(messageList[b].id, false, null));
                  var delID = messageList[b].id;
                  //console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
                  if(delID){
                    gmail.users.messages.trash({
                      auth:auth,
                      userId: 'me',
                      id: delID,
                    }, function(err2, delObject){
                      if(err2){
                        console.log("The message with ID: "+ delID + " could not be deleted");
                        console.log(err2);
                        return;
                      }
                      else{
                        console.log(util.inspect(delObject, false, null));
                        console.log("Message was deleted with id: " + delID);
                      }
                    })
                  }
                }, 2000);
              }
```

The lines above where messageList has an actual number instead of a variable shows '157550983b6c1cb' (the apostrophes print out as well). On the line where I switch it with b, it throws:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined
       at Timeout.oneTimeout(.......etc)
       at tryOnTimeout(timers.js:232:11)
       at Time.listonTimeout(timers.js:202:5)
```

Does this mean that it is impossible to use the variable b inside the Timeout function? If so, how do I get around needing to iterate over the entire messageList with a break in between deletions?

Comment: What's you `b` and messageList values?

Comment: b is between 1 and the length of the array and should call that function for each one of those numbers. It throws an error on the very first loop though, so it was only ever 1 before it broke. messageList is a list of objects with two fields: id and threadId that can be viewed with util.inspect

Comment: Id `id` is not available in `messageList` and you try to access it, it'll give error

Comment: Yes, I know that is what the error is saying. The issue that I'm having is that in 3 of the 4 above console logs, I can see what I want. On the last one where I have "b" instead of the number 1, it says that object doesn't exist. When 1 is specified, it prints out the id just fine.

Comment: can you check your `b` value before that console?

Comment: asynchronous code strikes again ... the value of `b` by the time the FIRST `setTimeout(function(){` is called will be length (not length - 1) and therefore `messageList[b]` or in other words, `messageList[messageList.length]` is obviously undefined

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @abdulbarik - he may think the loop will iterate every two seconds this way - rather than set `length-2` callbacks to all fire at once after 2 seconds - there's also the question of why messageList[0] is totally ignored :p

Comment: That is true. I was attempting to get it to iterate length-1 number of times but wait 2 seconds in between each function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because setTimeout is asynchronous, the callback wont get called until the for loop has finished - at this point, b will be messageList.length - so too big

You want to wait 2 seconds between each iteration - one way to do this is with a recursive function call like this

```
var length = messageList.length;
function myFunction(b) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
        console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1], false, null));
        console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1].id, false, null));
        console.log(util.inspect(messageList[b].id, false, null));
        var delID = messageList[b].id;
        //console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
        if (delID) {
            gmail.users.messages.trash({
                auth: auth,
                userId: 'me',
                id: delID,
            }, function(err2, delObject) {
                if (err2) {
                    console.log("The message with ID: " + delID + " could not be deleted");
                    console.log(err2);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log(util.inspect(delObject, false, null));
                    console.log("Message was deleted with id: " + delID);
                }
            })
        }
        b += 1;
        if (b < length) {
            myFunction(b);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
if (messageList.length > 0) {
    myFunction(0);
}
// note - any code here will run immediately! 
// it wont wait for the "iteration" to complete - 
// if you need to wait for the above to finish, 
// that's a whole other set of problems
```

> as per comments, if you want the first iteration to run immediately, change the code to

```
var length = messageList.length;
function myFunction(b) {
    console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
    console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1], false, null));
    console.log(util.inspect(messageList[1].id, false, null));
    console.log(util.inspect(messageList[b].id, false, null));
    var delID = messageList[b].id;
    //console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
    if (delID) {
        gmail.users.messages.trash({
            auth: auth,
            userId: 'me',
            id: delID,
        }, function(err2, delObject) {
            if (err2) {
                console.log("The message with ID: " + delID + " could not be deleted");
                console.log(err2);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log(util.inspect(delObject, false, null));
                console.log("Message was deleted with id: " + delID);
            }
        })
    }
    if (b < length - 1) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, 2000, b + 1);
    }
}
if (messageList.length > 0) {
    myFunction(0);
}
// note - any code here will run immediately! 
// it wont wait for the "iteration" to complete - 
// if you need to wait for the above to finish, 
// that's a whole other set of problems
```

> If you want to have code that runs on completion of the iteration, things can be made a whole lot simpler with Promises - you could use this method regardless if you have code that runs on completion or not

```
messageList
.slice(1) // skip the first item in the array as per question code - remove this line to start at 0
.reduce(function(prom, messageItem, index) {
    return prom
    .then(function () {
        if (index) { // this avoids the 2 second wait on the first item
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
            });
        }
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
        console.log(util.inspect(messageItem, false, null));
        console.log(util.inspect(messageItem.id, false, null));
        var delID = messageItem.id;
        //console.log(util.inspect(messageList, false, null));
        if (delID) {
            gmail.users.messages.trash({
                auth: auth,
                userId: 'me',
                id: delID,
            }, function(err2, delObject) {
                if (err2) {
                    console.log("The message with ID: " + delID + " could not be deleted");
                    console.log(err2);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log(util.inspect(delObject, false, null));
                    console.log("Message was deleted with id: " + delID);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, Promise.resolve()) // this starts the promise chain
.then(function() {
    // this code gets called once the "loop" finishes
});
// code here does not wait for the "loop" to finish
// in fact it runs before the first messageList item is even processed
```

This code does **NOT** wait for `gmail.users.messages.trash` to complete before starting the wait for the next iteration - if you need to wait for that, then, again, that's a whole other problem, but very very easily handled when using the promise method

Comment: You are correct, it should be 0 but I was testing with random numbers and left it at 1

Comment: I am testing it now (the overall script takes some time to run) but so I know for future reference, why is there the setTimeout call that would start at b (which would be 0 to start) AND the if statement below the timeout call? Will that force it to try to delete each email twice?

Comment: `why is there the setTimeout call that would start at b (which would be 0 to start)` - because that's what your code does - did you want the first iteration to NOT have the delay? - the if statement is to only keep going to the next iteration `if b < length` - note the `b += 1` - which is the same as `b++` - it increments b

Comment: What I mean is that there are two recursive calls in the function. One within the timeout and one outside. It appears that because one is called if  b is less than the total length, and the other is called if the length is greater than 0, they both have the possibility of being called on the same b value? Is that incorrect?

Comment: no there are not- the call to myFunction(0) is outside myFunction, to start the ball rolling

Comment: the call to myFunction(0) is outside myFunction is only called if messageList has **any** items, i.e. a length > 0 .. the call at the end of myFunction checks to see if there's any more to do, and if so, calls itself with the next value of b - try the Promise code I've added instead :p

Answer (score 0):

That mainly happens because setTimeout being async.

You could try something like this:

```
for(var a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
    (function(){
        var currentI = a;
        setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('Hi: sec: ', currentI);
        }, 1000);
    }());
}
```

Using a variable inside, will help you maintain its state
You can check [this](http://reallifejs.com/the-meat/getting-closure/never-forget/) out.

Comment: question has changed enough that this is not going to be a useful answer